# How do I export DocuSign Account Settings, Users, and User profiles and then import them to a new account?

Tags: docusignapi

Just looking for a DocuSign link to import and export account settings to quickly setup multiple accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot export and import account settings, you can contact DocuSign support or your DocuSign's Account Manager to export it for you. And import settings are not possible as well, some one from DocuSign will compare two accounts using our internal tools. Once we find any difference in the account settings then you and DocuSign support person can help in changing the settings and make sure that no differences are present.